# Python: combine logging and wx so that logging stream is redirectet to stdout/stderr frame

Tags: python, logging, wxpython

Here's the thing:

I'm trying to combine the logging module with wx.App()'s redirect feature. My intention is to log to a file **AND** to stderr. But I want stderr/stdout redirected to a separate frame as is the feature of wx.App.

My test code:

```
import logging
import wx

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger("main.MyFrame")
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent = None, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = "MyFrame")
        self.logger.debug("MyFrame.__init__() called.")

    def OnExit(self):
        self.logger.debug("MyFrame.OnExit() called.")

class MyApp(wx.App):
    def __init__(self, redirect):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger("main.MyApp")
        wx.App.__init__(self, redirect = redirect)
        self.logger.debug("MyApp.__init__() called.")

    def OnInit(self):
        self.frame = MyFrame()
        self.frame.Show()
        self.SetTopWindow(self.frame)
        self.logger.debug("MyApp.OnInit() called.")
        return True

    def OnExit(self):
        self.logger.debug("MyApp.OnExit() called.")

def main():
    logger_formatter = logging.Formatter("%(name)s\t%(levelname)s\t%(message)s")
    logger_stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    logger_stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logger_stream_handler.setFormatter(logger_formatter)
    logger_file_handler = logging.FileHandler("test.log", mode = "w")
    logger_file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger_file_handler.setFormatter(logger_formatter)
    logger = logging.getLogger("main")
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    logger.addHandler(logger_stream_handler)
    logger.addHandler(logger_file_handler)
    logger.info("Logger configured.")

    app = MyApp(redirect = True)
    logger.debug("Created instance of MyApp. Calling MainLoop().")
    app.MainLoop()
    logger.debug("MainLoop() ended.")
    logger.info("Exiting program.")

    return 0

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    main()
```

Expected behavior is:
- a file is created named test.log
- the file contains logging messages with level DEBUG and INFO/ERROR/WARNING/CRITICAL
- messages from type INFO and ERROR/WARNING/CRITICAL are either shown on the console or in a separate frame, depending on where they are created
- logger messages that are not inside MyApp or MyFrame are displayed at the console
- logger messages from inside MyApp or MyFrame are shown in a separate frame

Actual behavior is:
- The file is created and contains:

```
main    INFO    Logger configured.
main.MyFrame    DEBUG   MyFrame.__init__() called.
main.MyFrame    INFO    MyFrame.__init__() called.
main.MyApp  DEBUG   MyApp.OnInit() called.
main.MyApp  INFO    MyApp.OnInit() called.
main.MyApp  DEBUG   MyApp.__init__() called.
main    DEBUG   Created instance of MyApp. Calling MainLoop().
main.MyApp  DEBUG   MyApp.OnExit() called.
main    DEBUG   MainLoop() ended.
main    INFO    Exiting program.
```

- Console output is:

```
main    INFO    Logger configured.
main.MyFrame    INFO    MyFrame.__init__() called.
main.MyApp      INFO    MyApp.OnInit() called.
main    INFO    Exiting program.
```

- No separate frame is opened, although the lines

```
main.MyFrame    INFO    MyFrame.__init__() called.
main.MyApp      INFO    MyApp.OnInit() called.
```

shouldget displayed within a frame and not on the console.

It seems to me that wx.App can't redirect stderr to a frame as soon as a logger instance uses stderr as output. wxPythons Docs claim the wanted behavior though, [see here.](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.App-class.html#__init__)

Any ideas?

**Uwe**

Answer (score 1):

When wx.App says it will redirect stdout/stderr to a popup window, what it means really is that it will redirect sys.stdout and sys.stderr, so if you directly write to sys.stdout or sys.stderr it will be redirected to a popup window e.g. try this

```
print "this will go to wx msg frame"
sys.stdout.write("yes it goes")
sys.stderr.write("... and this one too")
```

Problem here is that if wxApp is created after creating streamhandler, streamhandler is pointing to old(original) sys.stderr and sys.stdout not to the new ones which wxApp has set, so a simpler solution is to create wx.App before creating streap handler e.g. in code move `app = MyApp(redirect = True)` before logging initialization code.

Alternatively create a custom logging handler and write data to sys.stdout and sys.stderr or better create you own window and add data there. e.g. try this

```
class LogginRedirectHandler(logging.Handler):
        def __init__(self,):
            # run the regular Handler __init__
            logging.Handler.__init__(self)

        def emit(self, record):
            sys.stdout.write(record.message)

loggingRedirectHandler = LogginRedirectHandler()
logger_file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logger.addHandler(loggingRedirectHandler)
```

Comment: >logging doesn't write to sys.stdout or sys.stderr  

This is not quite true (if the docs are right(http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#module-logging.handlers)). As the docs state, sys.stderr is use if an instance of logging.handlers.StreamHandler is created without argument.

Comment: @Uwe, i have updated answer, you need to move wx.App creation before   Streamhandler creation

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work either as all logger instances created within MyApp or MyFrame won't be connected to the actual logger "main". "main"'s stream is redirected to wx's redirection-frame but "main.MyApp" and "main.MyFrame" loggers are no children of "main" as "main" doesn't exist upon creation of "main.MyApp" and "main.MyFrame". And as they have not set a formatter and handler, the don't know where to put the debug messages from within MyApp and MyFrame.

Comment: only option you have to write custom handlers

Comment: I decided to use Gabriel Genellina's LoggingWebMonitor (http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577025-loggingwebmonitor-a-central-logging-server-and-mon/) as solution.

Comment: @Uwe, but what that has to do with wx redirect?

Comment: I wanted debug messages in a separate window. Now I get them in a browser, not in a wx frame. But as it seems impossible on the first look to redirect a loggers stream to wx this was the time saving way. I tried writing an own logging handler but failed. And this solution covers both log messages created within wx and outside.

Comment: in that case, you could just open the log file in a good editor or `tail -f xxx.log` but anyway your question should have stated that, I have answered the question not the hidden objective you had

Answer (score 1):

The way I do this, which I think is more elegant, is to create a custom logging Handler subclass that posts its messages to a specific logging frame.

This makes it easier to turn GUI logging on/off at runtime.